# C# Web API error 406 with application/xml

Tags: c#, xml, webapi

I'm getting error 406 when I run Postman and I don't know why my web API didn't work:

## Controller

```cs
[HttpGet("ExportarXML")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public IEnumerable<Roupa> GetXML() 
{
    List<Roupa> listaRoupa = new List<Roupa>(); // creates new list of type Roupa
    string connectionString = Configuration["ConnnectionStrings:DatabaseDasCompras"];
    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Roupa;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new();
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) // iterates the list
    {
        Roupa newRoupa = new Roupa
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),
            Marca = dr["Marca"].ToString(),
            Tipo = dr["Tipo"].ToString(),
            Tamanho = dr["Tamanho"].ToString(),
            Preco = dr["Preco"].ToString()
        };
        listaRoupa.Add(newRoupa); // fills the list
    }
    return listaRoupa; // returns the  list
}
```

- Model:

```cs
public class Roupa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Tamanho { get; set; }
    public string Preco { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Server may not support XML response.

Comment: Do you have e.g. `services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();` in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`?

Comment: My friend you are a LEGEND!

Comment: thanks to ur input im going to be able to deliver this assignment like a boss and get a good grade